# Prints "none" when I run it /PYTHON

Tags: python

Running this code where I am asking the user if they want the code in reverse order.

Everything runs smoothly, however when the program runs the section `Do you want reverse order (y/n)`, it prints `None` on the next line for some reason?

Can anybody explain why/how I get this to stop?

```
def farmList():
    print("Please enter six farming animals: ")
    terms = []
    for counter in range(6):
        term = input("Please enter a farm animal")
        terms.append(term)


    reverseOrder = input("Do you want reverse order (y/n)")
    if reverseOrder == "y":
        print(terms[::-1])
    else:
        print(terms)

    whichTerm = int(input("Choose a number between 1-6, and the program will print that animal: "))

    print(terms[whichTerm-1])
```

Comment: Where is the call to `farmList`? What is the Python version you're using?

Comment: How exactly are you running this? Are you actually calling `farmList()` explicitly somewhere?

Comment: I'm running it Python 3.6.0 Shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `farmList()` properly, then changing `input` to `raw_input` should work for python 2.7.
For Python 2.7, `raw_input()` takes exactly what the user typed and passes it back as a string.
Else for Python 3, your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, at least in Python3 (see this thread for more information : [What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x))

Note that you only show a reversed list, you don't reverse `terms`, though :

```
Please enter six farming animals: 
Please enter a farm animala
Please enter a farm animalb
Please enter a farm animalc
Please enter a farm animald
Please enter a farm animale
Please enter a farm animalf
Do you want reverse order (y/n)y
['f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
Choose a number between 1-6, and the program will print that animal: 1
a
```

To reverse the list you could write :

```
if reverseOrder == "y":
    terms = terms[::-1]
```

So your code would become :

```
def farmList():
    print("Please enter six farming animals: ")
    terms = []
    for counter in range(6):
        term = input("Please enter a farm animal")
        terms.append(term)


    reverseOrder = input("Do you want reverse order (y/n)")
    if reverseOrder == "y":
        terms = terms[::-1]

    whichTerm = int(input("Choose a number between 1-6, and the program will print that animal: "))

    print(terms[whichTerm-1])

farmList()
```

For Python2.7, replace every occurence of `input()` to `raw_input()`.

Comment: How would I go about implementing this? Should I just use an IF statement?  Thanks for the advice, hadn't thought about that.